# Converting the "Type" of Field, From a "SHOW COLUMNS" query, to a useable prepared statements argument. PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I am querying my database for the Type of each column, then I am doing a prepared statement, based on the resulting columns. From my query I receive the "Type" of each column, however, prepared statements, to my understanding, needs, d i t b for the type.

My query spits out things like,
*double,
string,
int(11)*
Is there a built in function, or just an array of keys and values that will result with
`double = d; string = s; int(11) = i;`
Or do I need to manually create an area with each possible case?

I would like a more general, any case scenario array, as opposed to one fixed argument like "sid" because I will be changing tables and so the fixed argument wont work for every table.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Use PDO amd you do not need to specify the type for prepared statement parameters.

Comment: Please provide an example of the PHP you want, together with the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table in question.